# Some Properties of a Special Monotone Class in The Proof of The Monotone Class Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The monotone class lemma is stated in Folland as follows:
[image]

According to this, $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{C}(E)$, and also $\mathcal{C}(E)$ is a monotone class.

Can anyone tell me more about $\mathcal{C}(E)$ and its properties?

For example, can $\mathcal{C}(E)$ be a sigma-algebra?

For $F \in \mathcal{A}$ and $E \in \mathcal{A}$, what is the properties of $\mathcal{C}(F)$ \ $\mathcal{C}(E)$? When $\mathcal{C}(F)$=$\mathcal{C}(E)$?

Is $\bigcup_{E \in \mathcal{A}}\mathcal{C}(E)$ a sigma-algebra?